# Does it matter if a function returns int to a function returning BOOL on Windows?

Tags: c, winapi, int, return-value, return-type

In the following semi-pseudo code I'm taking input from a file and writing to the standard console output. The console then waits for keyboard input. Only the `Enter` and `q` keys are actioned.

If the `Enter` key is pressed, more output is printed to the console (assuming we do not read EOF). If the `q` key is pressed, the function will `return 1`. If we read `EOF`, the function will `return 0`.

```
int exit_early(const WCHAR *message)
{
    WCHAR ch[4];
    DWORD nChars;

    /* Read from file and print to standard output. Wait for keyboard input */
    do {
        while (ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ch, 1, &nChars, NULL))
        {
            if (ch[0] == VK_RETURN)
                break;
            else if (ch[0] == 'q') /* Exit on 'q' key */
                return 1;
        }
    } while (condition);
    /* other code */
    return 0;
}

BOOL wrapper(const WCHAR *message)
{
    BOOl ret;
    /* Get and set console mode */
    ret = exit_early(message);
    /* Restore console mode */
    return ret;
}

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{
    /* Load file. Send to wrapper().
       Keep going until EOF or early exit returned. */
    while (condition)
    {
        if (wrapper(str)) /* Breaks if TRUE. */
            break;
    }
    /* more code */
    return 0;
}
```

I have trouble understanding whether the `return` type is compatible. Does it matter that the `BOOL ret` recieves `0` or `1`? Or should this be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, given that `wrapper()` returns `BOOL`? I note that `windef.h` defines `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`.

I suppose what I'm asking is whether `exit_early()` and `wrapper()` should both `return int` or should both `return BOOL`.

Comment: Functionally, this will probably work since `1` is truthy and `0` is falsey in C. But if this is your code, why wouldn't you just make the return type and values of `exit_early` to be `BOOL`?

Comment: `BOOL` is a typedef for `int`, so it doesn't really matter. Many Windows API functions that return `BOOL` can return a nonzero value that's not equal to `TRUE`, so your function won't even be the first. (That's why `BOOL` return values should always be compared against `FALSE` rather than `TRUE`.)

Comment: `BOOL` looks like a `typedef`. The actual `bool` type was introduced in C99 (as a `typedef` of `_Bool`), which was not implemented by microsoft. Either way: if it's a typedef, it doesn't really matter. If it isn't a `typedef`, you can convert an int to a bool by writing `!!intval` or something. Some implementations of `_Bool` implement it as a char-like type (`sizeof(_Bool)` being 1), but assigning an int hasn't caused issues for me so far

Comment: @lurker, what happens if I want to return a value other than `1` or `0`? Wouldn't this break the `BOOL` type? EDIT: No, it wouldn't, because others have said `BOOL` is a typedef for `int`.

Comment: @HughMcMaster it depends upon the "contract" between the function and the rest of the world that calls it. If you really mean to say that the return value is an integer which can have many values, and sometimes you only care if the value is non-zero, then why not have the code written that way instead of treating it like a BOOL? As I said, technically it will work because in C any non-zero value is truthy.

Comment: @T.C. What use is `BOOL` if I can return a value of, say, `5` and still enter an `if` block? I thought the point of `TRUE` or `FALSE` was to be just that?

Comment: @lurker, at the moment I'm only returning 0 or 1, so I thought a BOOL type would be appropriate (as `TRUE` or `FALSE`). But, as you say, all I actually care about is checking whether the return value is non-zero. So the code could be written either way.

Comment: You should be OK here (as others have noted), but you could always set `ret = exit_early(message) ? TRUE : FALSE` to be super-safe.

Comment: @HughMcMaster Anything nonzero is truthy as far as C is concerned. [`GetMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) for instance returns -1 on error and some other nonzero value if it gets an message and it isn't `WM_QUIT`, even though its return type is `BOOL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bits-wise, it's OK for the same reason everyone else mentioned: `BOOL` is a typedef of `int`.

However, you may want to consider whether it's right from a semantics standpoint, with the callee's documented contract.

- If `exit_early()`'s returned `int` is documented to have a boolean value, then it's OK, though if you have write access to `exit_early()` you should contemplate changing its return type to `BOOL` to make it obvious.
- If `exit_early()` is not guaranteed to return `0` or `1` with a connotation of truth or falseness, you should change your assignment to `ret = (exit_early(message) != 0);`.

Comment: This is an interesting answer. MSDN's data types page defines `BOOL` as "A Boolean variable (should be TRUE or FALSE)." Does this mean `exit_early()` can have a `BOOL` type, but return `1` or `0` internally?

Comment: Since `TRUE` and `FALSE` are `#define`s of 1 and 0, I think my answer is the same: Bits-wise it's OK, but semantically it's better to use TRUE and FALSE (or comparison results).

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter because technically BOOL is just a typedef of 'int'. Here is it definition in WinDef.h:

```
typedef int BOOL;
```

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) is more info about the Windows API defined types.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to MSDN. It's very useful.

Comment: No problem - don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if you think it solved your issue :).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned BOOL is an int in disguise so that there isn't even a question.

If at some point (after porting to a more modern C/C++) BOOL gets typedef'ed to a true bool then an implicit integer conversion would happen: The compiler would map 0 to false and everything else to 1 upon assignment to `ret` in `wrapper`, possibly with a narrowing warning. Fine, too.

Comment: `BOOL` cannot ever be changed. The API is published and thus immutable. Realities aside, let's assume for a moment that `BOOL` did get changed to an alias for `bool`, and implicit conversion takes place: Now you broke [`GetMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) - this is not at all ok.

Comment: @IInspectable: I meant porting the prog, not the OS or API.

Comment: The `BOOL` data type is owned by the Windows Platform SDK. A *more modern C/C++* cannot change it.

Comment: @IInspectable As I said, it is conceivable that the presented code will be ported to a different platform which has a boolean type. (Although the presented code is fairly Windows specific, it may constitute just the Windows specific part of a larger program. E.g. I imagine that FractInt had code like this which needed to be adapted to X for XFractint.) On that new platform, BOOL conceivably may be or could be defined as bool (C++) or _Bool (C99). Having `exit_early` return int and convert it to bool in `wrapper` would be ok (which I think was part of what the OP wanted to know).